# Run Selenium testcase in Backend and UI element to trigger this test in front end

Tags: java, user-interface, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have written testcase in Selenium Java Webdriver-TestNG (Firefoxdriver) for some functionalities and UI related stuffs.

Like, to check if the font color and size in all pages match the criteria given by the client, Login process, registration process etc.

Now, my boss wants me to give the testcases to developers for doing the regression testing. But, he doesn't want me to give my code to them instead wants to,

- Create a UI for the same, so that the link to this UI can be given to the developers.
- Developer need to enter the URL of the page which they want to check and Submit
- Submit should trigger the testcase which I have written to test all font properties
- Give the result in UI PASS/FAIL with details

Can you guys please suggest a way to do this?

Thanks a lot,
Shari

Comment: Some of the information seems to be missing.
Need clarification on :-
* 2nd step :- developer will enter the url of page   
    Question :- Do all the Test scripts belong to all pages and do we
     require to login everytime?
* And the URL is the base URL of site or any URL of the site?

BTW , you can use jenkins for the UI. Developer can enter parameter in jenkins before running the job and you can initiate an email report as well(Some custom code might be required here)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... For some of the tests, URL will be the input, For eg,  checking broken links in a page, here developer gives URL as input from a text fields, and on submit, our Selenium Java code runs and gives a list of broken links. Similarly with font properties too.

Comment: For eg: the entered URL should trigger my function and take the input to the action, driver.get(urls) and do all tests written inside the function, return result and show the result in UI